# Bash script not working even when in my PATH

Tags: bash, centos

I created a simple bash script. The script works just fine.

When I run echo $PATH this prints my paths, I have:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin/:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

So i moved my script to /usr/local/bin and ran `chmod +x mybash.sh`. I've even `chmod 0777 mybash.sh`

Now, when I run ./mybash.sh I just get the "No such file or directory"

Why is this happening and where's the best place to put my scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the script is in your path, you can run it just with the filename: `mybash.sh` rather than the path to the file: `./mybash.sh`

Answer (score 2):

`./mybash.sh` means run `mybash.sh` from the current folder. If you've moved `mybash.sh` to `/usr/local/bin`, then it's no longer in `./` (your current folder), so it can't find it.

Either move to `/usr/local/bin` to run it using `./mybash.sh` or just use `mybash.sh` from any folder once you've moved it into a path folder.